# git pull results in conflict

Tags: git

I did git pull origin newbranch:newbranch ... but for some reason.. this tried merging newbranch in my origin with master in local.. and it resulted in conflict ..  1)how do i undo the half done merge?  2)how do i pull newbranch in origin to a new branch in local repo named "newbranch"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this to reset back to your pre-merge state:

```
git reset --merge
```

(Or if you're using a version of git before `--merge` was available, use `--hard`.)

Then create and checkout your branch, and pull, merging into it:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git pull origin newbranch
```

Of course, you'll get the exact same conflicts as before, because you're merging into the same commit...